# Where do I place set statements with regards to a WITH clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

When I try to use a WITH statement to organise my code it fails when I have preceding code for USE, SET, and DECLARE.

I can't find the correct way to set these items once I introduce the WITH statement (they work fine without it).

I've tried moving the USE and SET and declare statements in all the places I can think of without success.

```
USE Database_name
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE
DECLARE @EndDate   AS DATE

SET @StartDate = GETDATE() -90 --'2018-12-01'
SET @EndDate   = GETDATE() -30

with slack as (
SELECT .....rest of query
)

SELECT * FROM slack
```

The error I get is "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon."

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to terminate SQL statements with a semi-colon. Not ending Transact-SQL statements with a semicolon [has been deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017).

```
SET @StartDate = GETDATE() - 90; -- this is a comment
SET @EndDate   = GETDATE() - 30;
WITH slack AS (
    SELECT *
)
SELECT * FROM slack;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a semicolon before with.

```
;with slack as (
SELECT .....rest of query
)

SELECT * FROM slack
```

Comment: This is wrong. You put a semicolon _after_ a statement.